# How to stream audio from Firebase Database to Phone (IOS) Using Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, firebase, audio, stream

I want to stream audio that is stored in my firebase database to my application using swift xcode. What is the correct way of coding this and setting it up in Firebase?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you using firestore, firebase storage or realtime database?

Comment: Hi Andre thanks for the response. I'm using Realtime database and firestorage. I haven't used firestore yet. But i'm stuck in how to build the backend for my music streaming app. Because i want to use firebase to beging with and than later on switch to AWS when i have more users.